# Error "Pure virtual function called" in template derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pure-virtual

I need to make a general `Robot` which would find path on a general `Surface`.

So here is my `Surface` interface:

```
template <typename P>
class Surface {
public:
    virtual int distance(const P& from, const P& to) const = 0;
    virtual bool check(const vector<P>& path, const P& from, const P& to) const = 0;
    virtual vector<P> lookAround(const P& at) const = 0;
};
```

Here I create a simple `PlanarSurface`:

```
class PlanarSurface : public Surface<pair<int, int>> {
public:
    using point_type = pair<int, int>;
    int distance(const point_type& from, const point_type& to) const override {
        return to.first - from.first + to.second - from.second;
    }

    bool check(const vector<point_type>& path, 
               const point_type& from, 
               const point_type& to) const override {
        return true; // there would be the check
    }

    vector<point_type> lookAround(const point_type& at) const override {
        vector<point_type> result;
        //...
        return result;
    }
};
```

Now I create an abstract class `Robot` so that every user-implemented robot would extend it:

```
template <typename P>
class Robot {
public:
    Robot(const Surface<P>& s): surface(s) {}
    vector<P> findPath(const P& from, const P& to) {
        auto path = searchPath(from, to);
        if (surface.check(path, from, to)) {
            return path;
        }
        throw runtime_error("path not found or incorrect");
    }
private:
    virtual vector<P> searchPath(const P& from, const P& to) = 0;
protected:
    const Surface<P>& surface;
};
```

There `searchPath` private method would be responsible for custom search algorithm, defined in children of `Robot`.
Suppose I have one:

```
template <typename P>
class MyRobot: public Robot<P> {
public:
    MyRobot(Surface<P> m): Robot<P>(m) {}
private:
    vector<P> searchPath(const P& from, const P& to) override {
        vector<P> result;
        // ...
        // use one of surface's virtual methods
        auto dist = this->surface.distance(from, to); // Pure virtual function called!
        cout << dist << endl;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
};
```

And finally the `main` function:

```
int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
    PlanarSurface plane;
    MyRobot<pair<int, int>> robot(plane);
    robot.findPath({1,2}, {3,4});
    return 0;
}
```

So the problem is that as the reference to `surface` is stored in base `Robot` class we can't specify it's type with some derived of `Surface` class. So the type of the reference can only be `Surface<P, M>`.

We need to use `surface`'s `distance` and `lookAround` methods in our search algorithm in every child of `Robot`. But in `Surface<P, M>` they are pure virtual. And they can be implemented only in children of `Surface<P, M>`.

Help me please! Maybe I missed something obvious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
MyRobot(Surface<P> m) : Robot<P>(m) {}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value
```

change it to accept a reference instead

```
MyRobot(Surface<P>& m) : Robot<P>(m) {}
```

Interestingly both MSVC and gcc diagnose this problem along the lines of

> invalid abstract parameter

while clang doesn't even emit a warning about this (at the time of writing this post - 4.0)